# Outputs are null from Apex class in flow?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, lead-conversion

I am trying to autoconvert leads using a apex class, I am trying to manually assign the outputs from the class into variables but the outputs are always null.

I am relatively new to this so not really sure what I can do to fix this issue!

[image: Null Input]

I have tried creating a collection variable but it doesn't let me add it to the apex action output values.

Any help and advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Thanks to a suggestion I have updated and added the class with a new parameter.

These are the outputs I am now receiving.

[image]

`Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert, false);`

Here is the code I have:

```
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'CLONE Auto Convert Leads')
    public static List<LeadConvertResultWrapper> LeadAssign(List<LeadConversionRequest> leadConversionRequests) {
        List<LeadConvertResultWrapper> leadConvertResults = new List<LeadConvertResultWrapper>();

        try {
            List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

            for (LeadConversionRequest request : leadConversionRequests) {
                Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
                Leadconvert.setLeadId(request.LeadId);
                Leadconvert.setAccountId(request.AccountId);
                Leadconvert.setContactId(request.ContactId);
                Leadconvert.setOpportunityId(request.OpportunityId);
                Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus('Recycled');
                MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);
            }

            if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) {
                Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert, false);

                // Process the results and add to the output variable
                for (Database.LeadConvertResult result : lcr) {
                    LeadConvertResultWrapper wrapper = new LeadConvertResultWrapper();
                    wrapper.isSuccess = result.isSuccess();
                    wrapper.leadId = result.getLeadId();
                    wrapper.contactId = result.getContactId();
                    wrapper.opportunityId = result.getOpportunityId();
                    wrapper.accountId = result.getAccountId();
                    leadConvertResults.add(wrapper);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log or handle the exception as needed
            System.debug('Exception during lead conversion: ' + e.getMessage());
        }

        return leadConvertResults;
    }

    public class LeadConversionRequest {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'LeadId' required = true)
        public Id LeadId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'AccountId' required = false)
        public Id AccountId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'ContactId' required = false)
        public Id ContactId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'OpportunityId' required = false)
        public Id OpportunityId;
    }

    public class LeadConvertResultWrapper {
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Is Success')
        public Boolean isSuccess;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Lead ID')
        public Id leadId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Contact ID')
        public Id contactId;

        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Opportunity ID')
        public Id opportunityId;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label = 'Account ID')
        public Id accountId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm - is the conversion successful? i.e. IsSuccess = true? One thing I might add to the LeadConvertResultWrapper is an error variable, which you can set from LeadConvertResult is there are errors, and then see in the flow debug

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC the class I used before trying to get any outputs was successfully converting leads to contacts. When I add a variable to the IsSuccess that is also coming back as null.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);
```

Will throw a `DmlException` if the conversion fails. This means that your output won't be correct in that case. Instead, add the `allOrNone` parameter, set to `false`:

```
Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert, false);
```

This is the only way to get the `LeadConvertResult` data back in the event of an error.

Comment: I added the parameter! I am now getting some outputs! 

Will add the info and screenshot to the original question post. The IsSuccess is now false but it is returning the LeadId, so thank you!

Comment: @Chelsea You should add an error property so you can see the output. Probably a null pointer exception, if I had to guess. Your code should not try to populate any Id values that will be null, as this can cause problems.